# Reading line count using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, counting

How to calculate the number of rows in a file which we have uploaded. The file might be either a text file or a CSV or Excel file.

I'm using the folowing code to get the record count like this:

```
Dim FileCount = From lin1 As String In File.ReadAllLines(hidFilePath.Value.ToString())
Let dd = lin1.Count
Select dd
Dim file_count As Integer =  FileCount.Count
```

but in some cases the count is wrong.

Comment: @chinnu: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 6):

`ReadAllLines` returns a string array, so you can simply take the length of the array.

```
Dim file_count As Integer = _
    File.ReadAllLines(hidFilePath.Value.ToString()).Length
```

Comment: And if it does not work for some reason, the ReadAllLines has an overload where you can send in a different encoding, wich may help in some cases: IO.ReadAllLines(path,encoding)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: read question to fast and answered with a loop solution

You can set your linecount as an integer and have the reader read to the end of the file.

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader("file path here")    
Dim lineCount As Integer = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), Environment.NewLine).Length
sr.Close()
```

You can use a count variable and loop through the file until theres nothing

```
        ''name count and set it to 0
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0  
        Dim obj As StreamReader
        obj = New StreamReader("C:\...\source.txt")
        ''loop through the file until the end
        Do Until obj.ReadLine Is Nothing
            count = count + 1
        Loop
        ''close file and show count
        obj.Close()
        MessageBox.Show(count)
```

Comment: OP specifically asks for a solution that does not require to loop through the entire file.

Comment: Ahhhh haha did not see that line. I jumped the gun, ill leave for reference to others who may stumble here.

Comment: This RealAllLines method works for getting the count for all text files. but i want to get the rows count for excel files too...yes i need without loop through..