# How to get the exact number of rows of an Excel file with VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I just started working with VB.NET. In my application I will need to have the exact number of used rows in an Excel file.

I had a look at this post                                      [Reading line count using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829367/reading-line-count-using-vb-net) and I tried all the answers but I've never got the exact number of rows.

Could anybody help me out?

Hello in actually I work with SQL SERVER 2008 I tried this code

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.Process
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools
Imports Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim selectedFile As String = String.Empty

        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        selectedFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        If (selectedFile IsNot Nothing) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(selectedFile)

        End If
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim fullPath As String
        Dim fileResult As String
        Dim numRow As Integer
        fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

        fileResult = Path.GetFileName(fullPath)
        Dim file_count As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath).Length
        MsgBox(file_count)
```

but again the count is not correct, and I really do not know why!!

Comment: It depends on how you are accessing the file.  How are you opening the Excel file?  VSTO?

Comment: I open the file from a filedialog! plz take a look at the edited question thanks in advance!

Comment: File.ReadAllLines will open a TEXT file and allow you to read all the lines from it.  A spreadsheet is not a text file so this will not work. What exactly do you need? Is it the number of used rows in the first worksheet? In all worksheets?  Why is the number of used rows important? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In fact I have to put a condition for the number of rows, for example if it's bigger than a number this file will not be valid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello finally I got the solution:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim fullPath As String
    Dim fileResult As String
    Dim numRow As Integer
    fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

    fileResult = Path.GetFileName(fullPath)

    Dim obook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oapp As Excel.Application
    oapp = New Excel.Application
    obook = oapp.Workbooks.Open(fullPath)
    numRow = 3

    While (obook.ActiveSheet.Cells(numRow, 1).Value IsNot Nothing)
        numRow = numRow + 1
    End While

    MsgBox(numRow)

End Sub
```

and you have to add the folowing references:

```
Microsoft Excel 12.0 Library
Microsoft Office 12.0 Library
Microsoft Office Tools v9.0
Microsoft visual Basic for application extensibility
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the used rows for a routine importing an Excel worksheet into  SQL 2008 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and VB.NET 2010 and I used just:

```
usedRowsCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the data of an Excel file into datatable and count the rows:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub getexcelfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim excelfile As New OpenFileDialog()
        excelfile.ShowDialog()
        If (excelfile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
            Return
        Else
            Dim file As String = excelfile.FileName
            Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(str)
            con.Open()
            Dim ds As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", con)
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            ds.Fill(dt)
            Dim rowcount As Integer
            rowcount = dt.Rows.Count()

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I work with SQL server 2008 and sorry for the delay I was working on another part of the project!

Comment: the problem with this solution, that it works only with 2003 excel files not of those of 2007(.xlsx)! for that you have to change the string connection to this "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;" an it will work for both :)!

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub getexcelfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim excelfile As New OpenFileDialog()
    excelfile.ShowDialog()
    If (excelfile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        Return
    Else
        Dim file As String = excelfile.FileName
        Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(str)
        con.Open()
        Dim ds As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        ds.Fill(dt)
        Dim rowcount As Integer
        rowcount = dt.Rows.Count()

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should have edited your first answer instead of posting another one. I copied your example into your first answer; you should delete this one.